Gradient and intermediate value theorem
I'm having trouble with an optimization problem. I have a continuous and concave objective function $\mathcal{O} : \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I have strong evidence (numerical simulations) that $\nabla \mathcal{O}$ reaches $0$ in $(0,1)^n$. Nonetheless, as I cannot express it in a closed form solution, I do not know how to rigorously prove the statement "$\nabla \mathcal{O}$ reaches $0$ in $[0,1)^n$".
My first idea was to use a generalization of the intermediate value theorem, knowing that, component-wise, $\exists a \in (0,1), \exists b \in (0,1)$, such that $\nabla \mathcal{O}_i(a) <0$ and $\nabla \mathcal{O}_i(b) >0$ but I find myself not convinced by this argument as I think that I would need that all components are null at the same point. I also have that: $\nabla \mathcal{O}(0)>0$ and $\nabla \mathcal{O}((1,1,...,1))<0$.
What are your thoughts on the matter? Have you any theorem to recommand or any approach to suggest? I know that I do not provide an expression for $\mathcal{O}$, but I would like a general method to deal with this type of problems.
